# PyQt style guide

Tags: python, qt, coding-style, pyqt

I'm currently writing my first open source Qt app in Python, using PyQt bindings. I've noticed some habits when coding, that might impair the readability of my code. Specifically, I have these concerns:

### Properties

---

Because I don't want to have an endless list of functions with decorators filling up all my classes with hundreds of lines, I have made myself sort of a template to fit each (PyQt-) property into a single line of code, thereby throwing PEP-8 completely out of the window and burying it six feet under:

```
propertyName = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(functionThatGetsThePropertyValue()),fset=lambda self,x:[defaultFunc1(),defaultFunc2(),] if x is None else [None for (variableToSet1,variableToSet2,) in ((x,otherInputVariables_inThisCaseOnlyX),) for _ in (functionToCall1(x),functionToCall2(x),)] )
```

Here are a few examples:

```
styleRules         = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(self.styleSheet()                   ),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('styleRules','')]                                 if x is None else [None                                                                                 for _ in (self.setStyleSheet(Helper.styleSheetDictToString(Helper.updateStyleSheet(self.styleSheet(),x))))] )
handle1Style       = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(self.splitter.handle(1).styleSheet()),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('handle1Style','background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)')] if x is None else [None for (self.settings['handle1Style'      ],) in ((x,),)                           for _ in (self.splitter.handle(1).setStyleSheet(x),)                                                      ] )
handle2Style       = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(self.splitter.handle(2).styleSheet()),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('handle2Style','background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)')] if x is None else [None for (self.settings['handle2Style'      ],) in ((x,),)                           for _ in (self.splitter.handle(2).setStyleSheet(x),)                                                      ] )
handle3Style       = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(self.splitter.handle(3).styleSheet()),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('handle3Style','background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)')] if x is None else [None for (self.settings['handle3Style'      ],) in ((x,),)                           for _ in (self.splitter.handle(3).setStyleSheet(x),)                                                      ] )
keywordCollapsible = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(self.splitter.isCollapsible(1)      ),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('keywordCollapsible',False)                     ] if x is None else [None for (self.settings['keywordCollapsible'],) in ((True if x=='true'else False,),) for _ in (self.splitter.setCollapsible(1,True if x=='true'else False),)                                   ] )
controlCollapsible = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(self.splitter.isCollapsible(3)      ),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('controlCollapsible',False)                     ] if x is None else [None for (self.settings['controlCollapsible'],) in ((True if x=='true'else False,),) for _ in (self.splitter.setCollapsible(3,True if x=='true'else False),)                                   ] )
splitterSizes      = pyqtProperty(QVariant,fget=lambda self:QVariant(tuple(self.splitter.sizes())        ),fset=lambda self,x:[self.setProperty('splitterSizes',(0,0,0,0))                      ] if x is None else [None for (self.settings['splitterSizes'     ],) in ((x,),)                           for _ in (self.splitter.setSizes(x),)                                                                     ] )
```

It's

- compact,
- somewhat readable (to me, at least),
- easily editable and has
- no disadvantage in regards to functionality or extensibility.

Contrast this with the more PEP-8 conform one:

```
    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def styleRules(self):
        return self.styleSheet()
    @styleRules.setter
    def styleRules(self,x):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('styleRules','')
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(Helper.styleSheetDictToString(Helper.updateStyleSheet(self.styleSheet(),x)))

    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def handle1Style(self):
        return self.splitter.handle(1).styleSheet()
    @handle1Style.setter
    def handle1Style(self):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('handle1Style','background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)')
        else:
            self.settings['handle1Style'] = x
            self.splitter.handle(1).setStyleSheet(x)

    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def handle2Style(self):
        return self.splitter.handle(2).styleSheet()
    @handle2Style.setter
    def handle2Style(self):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('handle2Style','background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)')
        else:
            self.settings['handle2Style'] = x
            self.splitter.handle(2).setStyleSheet(x)

    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def handle3Style(self):
        return self.splitter.handle(3).styleSheet()
    @handle3Style.setter
    def handle3Style(self):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('handle3Style','background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)')
        else:
            self.settings['handle3Style'] = x
            self.splitter.handle(3).setStyleSheet(x)

    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def keywordCollapsible(self):
        return self.splitter.isCollapsible(1)
    @keywordCollapsible.setter
    def keywordCollapsible(self):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('keywordCollapsible', False)

        else:
            self.settings['keywordCollapsible'] = True if x == 'true' else False
            self.splitter.setCollapsible(1,True if x == 'true' else False)

    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def controlCollapsible(self):
        return self.splitter.isCollapsible(3)
    @controlCollapsible.setter
    def controlCollapsible(self):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('controlCollapsible',False)

        else:
            self.settings['controlCollapsible'] = True if x == 'true' else False
            self.splitter.setCollapsible(3,True if x == 'true' else False)

    @pyqtProperty(QVariant)
    def splitterSizes(self):
        return tuple(self.splitter.sizes())
    @splitterSizes.setter
    def splitterSizes(self):
        if x is None:
            self.setProperty('splitterSizes',(0,0,0,0))
        else:
            self.settings['splitterSizes'] = x
            self.splitter.setSizes(x)
```

Is my style acceptable or should I switch to the more verbose version? If so, why?

### Subclassing

---

I have the tendency to subclass virtually every Qt object I use. I just like to define the attributes and properties of my widgets from inside the widgets instead of having the parent do all the work.

How do I know, whether subclassing a particular instance is appropriate? When it has its own methods, properties, event handlers? Should I *only* subclass when I know I will be creating multiple instances of the new class or is it acceptable to do it just for aesthetic purposes?

### Nested Classes

---

Because I create so many Classes, I group them together in the class of their parent, though I've heard people discouraging the use of nested Python classes as they have no real purpose. Are there any other reasons not to do it or is it OK to nest the classes for the sole reason of grouping them?

Comment: Usually I wouldn't mind too much having properties jammed onto one line, but in your case it's getting a little excessive. Scrolling my editor sideways would annoy me more than reading/editing multiple lines.

Comment: A vague rule for subclassing would be to do it if you need to define/redefine methods, but not if you are just setting property values. E.g. don't subclass a button just to set its text or connect its signals, even if you have lots of instances. But do subclass if you want to redefine its `__init__` or `setText` method. It's often fine to subclass to create a single instance as commonly is the case with `QApplication`.

Comment: @figs So essentially you are saying that if my subclass _only_ contans the `__init__` method, it should probably not be its own class, right? Also, do you know any useful resources on these topics?

Comment: It's fine to subclass even if you only have an `__init__` method. That's often how `QApplication` is subclassed. [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/urbansim/books/pyqt-book.pdf) is a good read.

Comment: @figs Thanks for the link, though it seems (at first glance), that this book is more about the general practice of developing a Qt app with PyQt (which is still great!), but do you know if it contains any information on programming style conventions, mainly how to not cause a headache to the reader of my code?

Comment: Just google around. The book should imply good practices of when and when not to subclass, etc.